# Hidden gems of Log4Net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm curious if anyone has familiarity with Log4Net (particularly the c# library) can share what they think are the most useful features that someone new to the library might overlook or misunderstand.

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more levels than the ones exposed by the helper methods (`ILog.Debug`, `ILog.Fatal`, etc) of the `ILog` interface. For log4net version 1.2.10.0 you have the following levels and associated cut off values used to filter messages in the loggers configuration:

```
OFF: 2147483647
EMERGENCY: 120000
FATAL: 110000
ALERT: 100000
CRITICAL: 90000
SEVERE: 80000
ERROR: 70000
WARN: 60000
NOTICE: 50000
INFO: 40000
DEBUG: 30000
FINE: 30000
TRACE: 20000
FINER: 20000
VERBOSE: 10000
FINEST: 10000
ALL: -2147483648
```

They can be used like in the following snippet where `Log` is of type `ILog`:

```
Log.Logger.Log(null, log4net.Core.Level.Emergency, "Help!", null);
```

Answer (score 3):

A very important feature for me are [context properties](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx) (global or per thread). This allows me to attach arbitrary information to log messages (e.g. an order number so you can track a specific order as it is processed by various systems).